# Rails Integration for TinyMCE with advanced doesn't show all tool buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I'm using Rails 3.2 and the tinymce-rails gem.

I created my tinymce.yml file with the following content:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
```

I added

```
<%= tinymce_assets %>
```

to the view I need the html editor and, I added this text area:

```
  <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "tinymce" %>
```

Finally, I added this to the end of my view file:

```
<%= tinymce %>
```

to the same view, inside my form.

The issue is that I just see a few tool options (see my screenshot). How can I get the whole thing, specifically the image uploader?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

```
gem update tinymce-rails
bundle update
```